# Android save info on return to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, save, return

very new to android and wondering how I can make this sample code return to where it left off instead of having to reload the pictures on returning to the screen. Right now when I exit the screen and return I have to start all over. I have read and trying to understand the Android documents but having trouble making this work or where to begin... thanks everyone!

```
  package com.windmillagency;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;








import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidFlickrActivity extends BT_activity_base {



    public String thisActivityName = "Flickr";

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    BackgroundThread backgroundThread;

    public class FlickrImage {
        String Id;
        String Owner;
        String Secret;
        String Server;
        String Farm;
        String Title;

        Bitmap FlickrBitmap;

        FlickrImage(String _Id, String _Owner, String _Secret, 
                String _Server, String _Farm, String _Title){
            Id = _Id;
            Owner = _Owner;
            Secret = _Secret;
            Server = _Server;
            Farm = _Farm;
            Title = _Title;

            FlickrBitmap = preloadBitmap();
        }

        private Bitmap preloadBitmap(){
            Bitmap bm= null;

            String FlickrPhotoPath = 
                    "http://farm" + Farm + ".static.flickr.com/" 
                    + Server + "/" + Id + "_" + Secret + "_m.jpg";

            URL FlickrPhotoUrl = null;

            try {
                FlickrPhotoUrl = new URL(FlickrPhotoPath);

                HttpURLConnection httpConnection 
                    = (HttpURLConnection) FlickrPhotoUrl.openConnection();
                httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpConnection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return bm;
        }

        public Bitmap getBitmap(){
            return FlickrBitmap;
        }

    }

    class FlickrAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context context;
        private FlickrImage[] FlickrAdapterImage;;

        FlickrAdapter(Context c, FlickrImage[] fImage){
            context = c;
            FlickrAdapterImage = fImage;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return FlickrAdapterImage.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return FlickrAdapterImage[position];
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ImageView image;  
            if (convertView == null) {
                image = new ImageView(context);  
                image.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));  
                image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);  
                image.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);   
            } else {  
                image = (ImageView) convertView;    
            }  

            image.setImageBitmap(FlickrAdapterImage[position].getBitmap());

            return image; 
        }

    }

    FlickrImage[] myFlickrImage;

    /*
     * FlickrQuery = FlickrQuery_url 
     * + FlickrQuery_per_page 
     * + FlickrQuery_nojsoncallback 
     * + FlickrQuery_format
     * + FlickrQuery_tag + q
     * + FlickrQuery_key + FlickrApiKey
     */

    String FlickrQuery_url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key=fdd73dc07613841fbe325b5103d673b7&user_id=65005067@N08&per_page=25&format=json";
    String FlickrQuery_per_page = "&per_page=10";
    String FlickrQuery_nojsoncallback = "&nojsoncallback=1";
    String FlickrQuery_format = "&format=json";
    String FlickrQuery_tag = "&tags=";
    String FlickrQuery_key = "&api_key=";

    //  Apply your Flickr API:
    //  www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/apply/?
    String FlickrApiKey = "fdd73dc07613841fbe325b5103d673b7";


    final String DEFAULT_SEARCH = "flickr";

    EditText searchText;
    Button searchButton;

    Gallery photoBar;

    Bitmap bmFlickr;




    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.activityName = "AndroidFlickrActivity";
        BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ":onCreate"); 



        //reference to base layout..
            LinearLayout baseView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.baseView);

            //setup background colors...
            BT_viewUtilities.updateBackgroundColorsForScreen(this, this.screenData);

            //setup background images..
            if(backgroundImageWorkerThread == null){
                backgroundImageWorkerThread = new BackgroundImageWorkerThread();
                backgroundImageWorkerThread.start();
            }           





            //setup navigation bar...
            LinearLayout navBar = BT_viewUtilities.getNavBarForScreen(this, this.screenData);
            if(navBar != null){
                baseView.addView(navBar);
            }

            //inflate this screens layout file...
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)thisActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View thisScreensView = vi.inflate(R.layout.flickr, null);

            //add the view to the base view...
            baseView.addView(thisScreensView);  

       searchText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchtext);
        searchText.setText(DEFAULT_SEARCH);
        searchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.searchbutton);

        photoBar = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.photobar);

        searchButton.setOnClickListener(searchButtonOnClickListener);
    }


///////////////////////////////////////////////////
//activity life-cycle overrides


//onResume
@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
//Log.i("ZZ", thisActivityName + ":onResume");
tToast("onResume");
}       



private void tToast(String s) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, s, duration);
    toast.show();
}


//onPause
@Override
public void onPause() {
//Log.i("ZZ", thisActivityName + ":onPause");
super.onPause();
tToast("onPause");
}



//activity life-cycle overrides
///////////////////////////////////////////////////


    private Button.OnClickListener searchButtonOnClickListener
       = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AndroidFlickrActivity.this, 
                   "Progress", "Please Wait");

            backgroundThread = new BackgroundThread();
            backgroundThread.setRunning(true);
            backgroundThread.start();




           }};


    private String QueryFlickr(String q){

        String qResult = null;

        String qString = 
                FlickrQuery_url 
                + FlickrQuery_per_page 
                + FlickrQuery_nojsoncallback 
                + FlickrQuery_format 
                + FlickrQuery_tag + q  
                + FlickrQuery_key + FlickrApiKey;

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(qString);

        try {
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpClient.execute(httpGet).getEntity();

            if (httpEntity != null){
                InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
                Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(in);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String stringReadLine = null;

                while ((stringReadLine = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(stringReadLine + "\n");
                    }

                qResult = stringBuilder.toString();
                inputStream.close();
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return qResult;
    }

    private FlickrImage[] ParseJSON(String json){

        FlickrImage[] flickrImage = null;

        bmFlickr = null;
        String flickrId;
        String flickrOwner;
        String flickrSecret;
        String flickrServer;
        String flickrFarm;
        String flickrTitle;

        try {
            JSONObject JsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONObject Json_photos = JsonObject.getJSONObject("photos");
            JSONArray JsonArray_photo = Json_photos.getJSONArray("photo");

            flickrImage = new FlickrImage[JsonArray_photo.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < JsonArray_photo.length(); i++){
                JSONObject FlickrPhoto = JsonArray_photo.getJSONObject(i);
                flickrId = FlickrPhoto.getString("id");
                flickrOwner = FlickrPhoto.getString("owner");
                flickrSecret = FlickrPhoto.getString("secret");
                flickrServer = FlickrPhoto.getString("server");
                flickrFarm = FlickrPhoto.getString("farm");
                flickrTitle = FlickrPhoto.getString("title");
                flickrImage[i] = new FlickrImage(flickrId, flickrOwner, flickrSecret,
                        flickrServer, flickrFarm, flickrTitle);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return flickrImage;
    }

    public class BackgroundThread extends Thread{
        volatile boolean running = false;
        int cnt;

        void setRunning(boolean b){
            running = b;    
            cnt = 10;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String searchQ = searchText.getText().toString();
            String searchResult = QueryFlickr(searchQ);

            myFlickrImage = ParseJSON(searchResult);


            handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());

        }
    }





    Handler handler = new Handler(){

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            photoBar.setAdapter(new FlickrAdapter(AndroidFlickrActivity.this, myFlickrImage));
            Toast.makeText(AndroidFlickrActivity.this, 
                    "Images Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    };

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write your activity so that it is aware of its current state.

In your `onPause()` method, save that state in any manner that you like. SharedPrefs, storage to a database, to a flat file, etc.

In your `onResume()` method, read that state and restore it.

Comment: Not sure in this code where to place onPause and onResume? thank you

Comment: Those are methods of the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html class; since your class extends Activity you just add them as if they are your class methods -- in the same manner that you added the `onCreate()` method. http://terokarvinen.com/2011/lifecycle-code-example-android-oncreate-onpause-onresume demonstrates these and other activity lifecycle methods; you need to remove the toast that page presents, and instead use your own state store/retrieval.

Comment: Thanks for the link, understanding a little better now.. my biggest problem is this is borrowed example code and i don't know where to even place the lifecylcle event? could you show me in the code where you might place it? soooo new to this and trying to figure it out. have read tons of links

Comment: Please take a look at my edited code in the original question. Not sure what to put in my onPause and onResume to keep the images loaded when I return to activity, thanks

Comment: Get rid of the toasting in your code; the link has those just to prove they're being called. Search SharedPreferences for guidance on saving/restoring simple data. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html has an example (but it uses onCreate/onStop, though onStop is unreliable; you should use onPause/onResume).

Comment: Hi, in reading more about SharedPreferences it looks like it's gonna be tough to store images with SharedPreferences....any thoughts on it or other ideas greatly appreciated

Comment: I agree you don't want to store images in a SharedPreference, however you have everything normally available to you for your storage needs -- such as opening a regular file to store into.